# Css :after and :before pseudo element not working properly in IOS

Tags: html, css, pseudo-element

I am trying to dash after border in H tag using `:after` and `:before` it's working fine on desktop & android devices but create issue in IOS devices
border made using :after and :before but text of h element doesn't display

below is a demo of other devices

[image]

below is a demo of IOS devices

[image]

```css
h2.service-heading {
  font-size: 36px;
  color: #762d2f;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  position: relative;
  display: table;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  max-width: calc(100% - 36px);
  position: relative;
}

h2.service-heading::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  width: calc(100% - 5px);
  display: block;
  height: 6px;
  border-bottom: 6px solid #762d2f;
  z-index: 9999;
  clear: both;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0px;
}

h2.service-heading::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  width: 10px;
  display: block;
  height: 6px;
  border-bottom: 6px solid #762d2f;
  z-index: 9999;
  clear: both;
  bottom: 0px;
  right: -10px
}
```

```html
<h2 class="service-heading" align="center"> Our Services</h2>
```

Can anyone help with this
Thanks in advance

Comment: Your snippet works fine on my iPad (IOS 14.4) and I can't see anything in the given code that would be problematic for IOS. Could you check that the snippet as given doesn't work for you, otherwise there may be something else in other code that is having this effect. Also, what version of IOS are you testing on?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to pseudo element for that. Can be made easily with only background.

```css
h2.service-heading {
  font-size: 36px;
  color: #762d2f;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  display: table;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  max-width: calc(100% - 36px);
  padding-right: 15px;
  background: linear-gradient(#762d2f, #762d2f)  0 100% / calc(100% - 15px) 6px no-repeat,
              linear-gradient(#762d2f, #762d2f) 100% 100% / 10px 6px no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<h2 class="service-heading" align="center"> Our Services</h2>
```

Also can be used some CSS variables to control everything easily.

```css
h2.service-heading {
  --border-height: 6px;
  --second-border-width: 20px;
  --border-gap: 10px;
  font-size: 36px;
  color: #762d2f;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  display: table;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  max-width: calc(100% - 36px);
  padding-bottom: 5px; /* bottom distance of border */
  padding-right: calc(var(--second-border-width) + var(--border-gap));
  background: linear-gradient(#762d2f, #762d2f)  0 100% / calc(100% - (var(--second-border-width) + var(--border-gap))) var(--border-height) no-repeat,
              linear-gradient(#762d2f, #762d2f) 100% 100% / var(--second-border-width) var(--border-height) no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<h2 class="service-heading" align="center"> Our Services</h2>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the similar problem: dropdown-arrow for menu item performed as pseudoclass `::after` didn't work for IOS. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7QRBx.png)

Next code snippet I utilized for SASS:

```
.nav-link {
      border-top: 1px solid var(--color-white);
      color: var(--color-white);
      font-size: 18px;
      line-height: 22px;
      font-weight: 400;
      text-decoration: none;
      padding: 10px 15px 10px 0;

      &::after {
        content: " ";
        border: none;
        background-image: var(--arrow-down);
        background-position: center center;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        width: 40px;
        height: 20px;
      }
  }
```

so the solution was to remove arrows from pseudoclass `::after` and perform it as a background image for menu item, like next:

```
.nav-link {
      display: block;
      border-top: 1px solid var(--color-white);
      color: var(--color-white);
      font-size: 18px;
      line-height: 22px;
      font-weight: 400;
      text-decoration: none;
      padding: 10px 15px 10px 0;
      background-image: var(--arrow-down);
      background-position: 98%;
      background-repeat: no-repeat;
      background: var(--arrow-down) no-repeat 98%;

      &::after {
        display: none;
      }
}
```

I've noticed that IOS14.4 and lower doesn't support background-image, and older versions IOS are needed only full form `background` not just `background-image`:

```
background: var(--arrow-down) no-repeat 98%;
```